# Grails: Can the asset pipeline be called from a taglib to include javascript dependencies?

Tags: javascript, grails, asset-pipeline, taglib

I have a taglib which has a dependency on a javascript file. I would like to utilize the asset pipeline to include this file from within my taglib.

Is this possible?

Does the asset pipeline have any functions that can be called from within a taglib, providing similar functionality that you would get by calling the following in a view:

```
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have not used asset pipeline. But you can call a tag lib from another. Try `asset.javascript(src: 'application.js')`.

Comment: @user1690588 - thanks, that worked. If you would like to post it as an answer, I would be happy to accept.

Comment: if you require specific js files on different pages / for different tags, why do you use the asset-pipeline at all? in my opinion, that does go well with the whole idea of the asset-pipeline (which is more like combining all static assets to one file, which is cached on the client). Why not using resource plugin instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not used asset pipeline. But you can call a tag lib from another. Try

```
asset.javascript(src: 'application.js')
```

Comment: This adds the javascript tag to the html but is not recognized if you are rendering the a template with ajax.

Comment: I cant find a solution like resources plugin does before: `r.require modules: "application"`